# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) (NextJs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using SVG's as a component in my nextjs app, but it's throwing this error message:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `Emoji`.
```

EmojiSection.js

```
import { useDocument } from "../../hooks/useDocument"
import { DEFAULT_EMOJI_OPTIONS } from "../../utils/emojis"

import Emoji from "./Emoji"

const EmojiSection = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id: docID } = router.query
  const { document: reactions } = useDocument(`solutions/${docID}/reactions`, "emojis")

  return (
    <div>
      {DEFAULT_EMOJI_OPTIONS.map((emoji) => (
        <Emoji key={emoji.label} reactions={reactions} emoji={emoji} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default EmojiSection
```

Emoji.js:

```
const Emoji = ({ reactions, emoji }) => {
  console.log(emoji)
  return (
    <>
      <span>
        <emoji.emoji className="w-16 h-16" />
      </span>
    </>
  )
}

export default Emoji
```

emoji.js

```
import ClappingHand from "../assets/emojiIcons/clappingHand.svg"
import Coin from "../assets/emojiIcons/coin.svg"
import Heart from "../assets/emojiIcons/heart.svg"
import Medal from "../assets/emojiIcons/medal.svg"

const DEFAULT_EMOJI_OPTIONS = [
  {
    emoji: Rocket,
    label: "rocket",
    slug: "rocket",
  },
  {
    emoji: Coin,
    label: "coin",
    slug: "coin",
  },
  {
    emoji: ClappingHand,
    label: "clapping hand",
    slug: "clapping-hand",
  },
  {
    emoji: Medal,
    label: "medal",
    slug: "medal",
  }
]

export { DEFAULT_EMOJI_OPTIONS }
```

[image]

`console.log(emoji)` in the `Emoji.js` file showing me this:

[image]

Anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Try passing uppercase `Emoji` prop. `<Emoji {...props} Emoji={emoji} />` and access it inside the `Emoji` component as `<Emoji.emoji className="w-16 h-16" />`. See if this works :-)

Comment: `Rocket`, `ClappingHand`, `Coin` are these react components or native svg files?

Comment: These are svg files.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass JSX props to the native `svg` icons. Try creating React components and convert those native html `svg` tags to React components and forward `props` to them.

So instead of importing `ClappingHand` from an svg file, create one `jsx` file `ClappingHand.jsx` inside `icons` folder and add following code.

```
import React from "react";

export const ClappingHand = ({
  ...props
}) => {
  // Make sure you convert native svg code to JSX. 
  // - e.g the class in native svg should be changed to className.

  // paste your svg code for respective icons below
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width={18}
      height={18}
      preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"
      viewBox="0 0 256 262"

      // forward the props to the svg tag
      {...props} 
    >
      <path
        fill="#4285F4"
        d="M255.878 133.451c0-10.734-.871-18.567-2.756-26.69H130.55v48.448h71.947c-1.45 12.04-9.283 30.172-26.69 42.356l-.204 1.622 38.755 30.023 2.685.268c24.659-22.774 38.875-56.282 38.875-96.027"
      />
      <path
        fill="#34A853"
        d="M130.55 261.1c35.248 0 64.839-11.605 86.453-31.622l-41.196-31.913c-11.024 7.688-25.82 13.055-45.257 13.055-34.523 0-63.824-22.773-74.269-54.25l-1.531.13-40.298 31.187-.527 1.465C35.393 231.798 79.49 261.1 130.55 261.1"
      />
      <path
        fill="#FBBC05"
        d="M56.281 156.37c-2.756-8.123-4.351-16.827-4.351-25.82 0-8.994 1.595-17.697 4.206-25.82l-.073-1.73L15.26 71.312l-1.335.635C5.077 89.644 0 109.517 0 130.55s5.077 40.905 13.925 58.602l42.356-32.782"
      />
      <path
        fill="#EB4335"
        d="M130.55 50.479c24.514 0 41.05 10.589 50.479 19.438l36.844-35.974C195.245 12.91 165.798 0 130.55 0 79.49 0 35.393 29.301 13.925 71.947l42.211 32.783c10.59-31.477 39.891-54.251 74.414-54.251"
      />
    </svg>
  );
};
```

Now, import the `ClappingHand` from the above component instead of svg file. Keep everything else as it is.

Do the same for all icons. Then it should work. If you have any further queries feel free to ask :-)